# Qt program fails to compile

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am writing this simple Qt application, but it is showing the following errors. 
Can anyone explain me why I am getting these errors? Below is the code snippet:

```
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
   QTextStream out(stdout);
   out << "console application\n";
}
```

Steps followed to compile:

```
qmake -project 
qmake .pro file 
make
```

After following the above mentioned steps, below is the output that I'm getting:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_REENTRANT  -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_SHARED -DQT_TABLET_SUPPORT -I/usr/share/qt3/mkspecs/default -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt3 -o text.o text.cpp
text.cpp:1:23: error: QTextStream: No such file or directory
text.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
text.cpp:5: error: ‘QTextStream’ was not declared in this scope
text.cpp:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘out’
text.cpp:6: error: ‘out’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [text.o] Error 1
```

Platform: Linux

Comment: Why are you specifying Qt3 header paths if you want Qt4 (according to your tags)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `qmake` and `make` instead of manually invoking the compiler.

```
cd YourProject/
qmake -project
qmake
make
./YourProjectTarget
```

and make sure the `qmake` version you're invoking is the Qt4 version, not the Qt3. You seem to have both versions installed, and you're probably invoking the Qt3 one.

Try this:

```
qmake -version
```

The output should be something like this

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

To be sure you're invoking the right `qmake` (Qt4), usually you can replace `qmake` commands with `qmake-qtX`, where `X` is the Qt version.

```
cd YourProject/
qmake-qt4 -project
qmake-qt4
make
./YourProjectTarget
```

Comment: @john if you have qt3 installed and you're not using it (for a very specific reason), please remove it.